# implementing mod 11 function in Java

Tags: java

good day,
what is the best way to implement the below function in java:
mod11(x) which calculates x mod 11, we assume x is either an integer or a formula. For example, mod11(14) returns 3, and mod11(3*7-30) returns 2.
I tried the below but it didn't work:
`

```
public static int PositiveMod(int value, int mod)
    {
        return ((value % mod + mod) % mod);
    }
```

`

`

```
public static double PositiveMod(double value, double mod)
    {
        return ((value % mod + mod) % mod);
    }
```

`
for example, i expect ((-7+1)/20) mod 11 to give out 3 but instead it gave me 10.7
like below
i = ((-7+1)/20) mod 11 = -6/9 mod 11 = 5*5 mod 11 = 3

Comment: `mod11(7*3 - 30)` == `mod11(-3)` which should be 8, not 9. `(-7+1)/20` is just `0` due to integer arithmetic (unless you can coerce into the `double` call, in which case it's `-6/20` i.e. `-0.3`, so 10.7 is correct). Lastly, for positive values you can simply use `value % mod`, and negatives can use `mod + (value % mod)` in java, which may be quicker than doing `%` twice.

Comment: thank you for the fast response, but I'm trying to get the below result
i = ((-7+1)/20) mod 11 = -6/9 mod 11 = 5*5 mod 11 = 3

Comment: `-6/20` != `-6/9` != `5*5` , so the laws of mathematics can't really help you there.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote two examples how to use it mathematical mod mathMod method and also default mod faultModCalJava mod. They will give the same result for positive numbers but for negative they have different output. More information here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

```
public class MainClass2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Math mod:" + mathMod(14, 11));
        System.out.println("Math mod:" + mathMod((3 * 7 - 30), 11));
        System.out.println("Math mod:" + mathMod(-13, 10));

        System.out.println("Default Java mod: " + defaultModCalJava(14, 11));
        System.out.println("Default Java mod: " + defaultModCalJava((3 * 7 - 30), 11));
        System.out.println("Default Java mod:" + defaultModCalJava(-13, 10));
    }

    private static int mathMod(int a, int m) {
        int positiveM = Math.abs(m);
        int result = a % positiveM;
        if (result < 0) {
            result = result + positiveM;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static int defaultModCalJava(int a, int m) {
        return a % m;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Math mod:3
Math mod:2
Math mod:7
Default Java mod: 3
Default Java mod: -9
Default Java mod:-3
```

Comment: thank you for the response but the requirements is to implement the below operator which is a little bit confuing:
i = ((-7+1)/20) mod 11 = -6/9 mod 11 = 5*5 mod 11 = 3

Comment: I don´t understand what this mean `i = ((-7+1)/20) mod 11 = -6/9 mod 11 = 5*5 mod 11 = 3` Is it several operation which you need to perform one after another or what is this = for? Are you sure that it is + but not = or some other symbol?

Comment: Note that modulo technically does not return negative integers. `-13 mod 10` is `7`, not `-3`. However, Java will print out `-3` (which is convenient in some cases, however...), this must be added to your divisor. It's better to think of it as a remainder operator.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is confusing.. the % operator is already the modulus operator, also known as remainder. ... so   14 % 11 = 3  is the same as mod11(14) = 3. There is no need to implement it as a new function.

In your equation, ((-7+1)/20) = -0.3, Its not clear why you would expect 3.

11 - 0.3 is 10.7, so that is where that answer comes from.

Comment: thank you for the fast response, but I'm trying to get the below result
i = ((-7+1)/20) mod 11 = -6/9 mod 11 = 5*5 mod 11 = 3

Comment: by the standard definition of mathematical operators, you are presenting an initial equation, "((-7+1)/20) mod 11" that does not equal 3. Each time you change it you seem to randomly pull operators and numbers out of the air... It looks like you are writing -6/9 = 5*5. This still makes no sense to me

Answer (score 1):

`%` is **not** a modulus operator. It is a [remainder operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3) and behaves as one would expect a remainder operator to behave.

```
System.out.println(-10 % 3); //  -3 r -1 since 3 * -3 + -1 == -10
System.out.println(10 % -3); //  -3 r  1 since -3 * -3 + 1 == 10 
System.out.println(-10 % -3);//   3 r -1 since 3 * -3 + -1 == -10
System.out.println(10 % 3);  //   3 r 1 since 3 * 3 + 1 == 10

prints as expected
-1
1
-1
1
```

A true mod function for  `n = x mod(m)` says there is some `k` where `x - n = km`

```
n = 20 mod(3) = 2  and k = 6   20 - 2 = 6*3
n = 20 mod(3) = -1 and k = 7   20 -(-1) = 3*7
```

The complete set of residues for any mod function is infinite and for the above is
`n = x - mk` for any integral value of `k`

So for the above the complete residue set would be `n = 20 - 3k`.  Any value returned would be a legitimate result.  The remainder function is simply a subset of size `one` of the aforementioned set of residues.

Having said that, this may help. This mod function simply corrects to the smallest positive value, assuming a positive modulus.

```
Mod mod11 = Mod.forModulus(11);
int k = mod11.of(-3);
System.out.println(k);

Mod mod121 = Mod.forModulus(121);
k = mod121.of(-12);
System.out.println(k);
```

prints

```
8
109
```

Here is a way to create mod function that just takes the target argument.

```
 interface Mod {
     int of(int value);
     static Mod forModulus(int mod) {
         return v-> {
             int u = v % mod;
             return u < 0 ? u + mod : u;
         };
     }
 }
```

The above may need some tweaking either because I misunderstood your issue or because the mod function needs to be more complex to satisfy your congruency relationships.